# Bind many control events to same handler, get sender

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm building a form Access with a load of TextBox controls on it. The `GotFocus()` event for every one of them will be exactly the same:

```
Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()
    Text1.BorderColor = RGB(100, 100, 255)
    ...
End Sub

Private Sub Text2_GotFocus()
    Text2.BorderColor = RGB(100, 100, 255)
    ...
End Sub

'... ad infinitum
```

This is, naturally, a maintanence nightmare and aesthetically a vast wad I have to keep scrolling past. I can throw `BorderColor = RGB(100, 100, 255)` etc into a function and have every handler call that function, but I'm still left with 3-line identical blocks for every single TextBox - throw in `LostFocus` and other events that are handled identically regardless of the TextBox, and it just becomes silly.

So the sensible thing to do would be to have a single `AllTextBoxes_GotFocus()` method, and have every TextBox's `On Got Focus` event point to that. Two problems though:

- I cannot see any functions or subs I've defined in VBA in the drop-down in the form designer, only `[Event Procedure]` (which generates the standard `Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()` method) and any Macros in the application. Which is... odd. Considering Macros have a `RunCode` option for calling VBA functions, it seems a bizarre round-the-houses way of calling code, having to get the control to call the macro to call the code. Surely there's a better way (and I think Macros can only call functions in modules, not on forms).
- I'm not sure how to get the sender, so I can set the appropriate control's border. VB.NET passes in the sender and event args in its events: `Private Sub Text1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)`, but VBA does not.

How can I handle mutliple events with a single handler, and get the sender of the event within the handler?

Comment: See here for how it's usually suggested to do this in VBA: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?235463-Control-array-in-VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I do it but know this will overwrite any custom GotFocus events

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim ctrl As Control
  For Each ctrl In Me.Form.Controls
        If ctrl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
           ctrl.GotFocus = "=changeColor('" & ctrl.name & "',100,100,255)"
           'For LostFocus
           ctrl.LostFocus = "=changeColor('" & ctrl.name & "')"
        End If
  Next ctrl
End Sub
Function changeColor(field As String, Optional red AS Integer =0 ,green AS Integer =0,blue As Integer = 0)
   Me.Form.Controls(field).BorderColor = RGB(red, green, blue)
End Function
```